# Convert clojure persistant vector to maps

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn clojure.

I am calling a function which is returning me an array of strings..

If I do:

```
(let [items (get-all-items)]
    (println (type items))
    (items))
```

the `type` of `items` is shown as `class clojure.lang.PersistentVector` where as the `items` value is like so:

```
[["Dogs"] ["Cats"] ["Capybaras"] ["Pygmy Hedgehogs"]]
```

I would like to convert this to a map in a format like this:

```
{ "Dogs" "Cats" "Capybaras" "Pygmy Hedgehogs" }
```

Does that make sense? Clojure maps can contain list of strings right?

I am only doing this because if I have it as a map, I can check if I have a pet in the list like this:

```
(contains? pets "Dogs")
; assuming the map is stored in pets variable
```

that fails if `pets` is a vector.

So If I can convert that to maps, how do I convert it? if not, how do I search for something in the vector?

(I like working with maps so I'd rather have maps - unless there is a strong reason not to do so)

<sub>ps: I've tried converting with [into](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into)  but that doesn't work either.</sub>

Comment: It sounds like you want a set, not a map. Does "Dogs" have a value other than itself, or are you just testing for membership?

Comment: @FrancisAvila, just testing for membership.. so maps always have a value with them? then sets would be better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect what you really want is a *set*, not a *map*. Maps store a value associated with a specific key. Sets store a unique list of values.

If your only use case is testing for membership, then you definitely want a *set*. You want a map if you are also associating some data with that key.

It's very easy to produce a set from any sequence. In your case:

```lisp
(set (flatten items))
;;=> #{"Pygmy Hedgehogs" "Dogs" "Cats" "Capybaras"}
```

[`flatten`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/flatten) removes the nesting on your lists giving you a sequence of strings. [`set`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/set) consumes the sequence and returns a set of the unique values in that sequence.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! thank you very much for the explanation, I definitely needed a set here, thanks!

Comment: Noooooo, not flatten, please! Flatten is never the right answer to anything. It happens to work fine when his data is just strings, but this same solution will not work at all if he wants his set to contain lists of things, say. Instead, use `apply concat` to remove just one level of nesting: `(set (apply concat items))`.

Comment: Noted, but I think in this case the OP doesn't want any collections (except strings) in his set.

Answer (score 3):

```
(apply assoc {} (flatten [["Dogs"] ["Cats"] ["Capybaras"] ["Pygmy Hedgehogs"]]))
;;=> {"Capybaras" "Pygmy Hedgehogs", "Dogs" "Cats"}
```

Comment: hi, why is there a comma after pygmy hedgehogs?

Comment: Maps are (key value) pairs. The comma separates the pairs. So the keys in this map are `Capybaras` and `Dogs`. (`Pygmy Hedgehogs` and `Cats` are their corresponding values.)

Comment: @FrancisAvila, thanks, I figured that after I read your comment.

Comment: Was too late too respond, and yeah, you probably wanted a set anyway :)